Is it possible to create backend service in load balancer that connects to different revisions of same cloud run service ? I want
Is it possible to  create backend service in load balancer that connects to different revisions of same cloud run service based on path (with route like domain.com/v1 and domain.com/v2)  ? What I found to create two different cloud run service and then configure but this is not what we want.

You can create serverless NEG on Cloud Run service and TAGS. So, associate revision to tags (current, next, for instance) and then create your backend servcies

The power of the tags feature is the capability to simply change them at the next iteration of your app, without changing the backend definition: you are not linked to the static revision name, but only to dynamic tag definition.
